# Need to pass a second instance of a provider

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to allow the current user to add new users to the app from within the app. However, I don't want to lose the current user's information that is held in a user provider. I populate the user provider with the current user's information when the user logs in.

I want to allow the current user to add a new user by filling in the data on a user profile screen and then when I save the new user I will send that data to the database.

I can't use the current user provider because it contains the current user information. I want to use a second instance of the user provider and call it newUser but I don't know how to do this or if it can be done.

Here is the user class:

```
class Users {
  String? userId;
  String? fName;
  String? lName;
  String? address1;
  String? address2;
  String? city;
  String? userState;
  String? zipCode;
  String? cellPhone;
  String? officePhone;
  String? email;
  String? companyId;
  String? companyName;
  String? mlsId;
  String? mls;
  String? businessType;
  String? deviceToken;

  Users(
      {this.userId,
      this.fName,
      this.lName,
      this.address1,
      this.address2,
      this.city,
      this.userState,
      this.zipCode,
      this.cellPhone,
      this.officePhone,
      this.email,
      this.companyId,
      this.companyName,
      this.mlsId,
      this.mls,
      this.businessType,
      this.deviceToken});

  Users copyWith({
    String? userId,
    String? fName,
    String? lName,
    String? address1,
    String? address2,
    String? city,
    String? userState,
    String? zipCode,
    String? cellPhone,
    String? officePhone,
    String? email,
    String? companyId,
    String? companyName,
    String? mlsId,
    String? mls,
    String? businessType,
    String? deviceToken,
  }) {
    return Users(
      fName: fName ?? this.fName,
      lName: lName ?? this.lName,
      address1: address1 ?? this.address1,
      address2: address2 ?? this.address2,
      city: city ?? this.city,
      userState: userState ?? this.userState,
      zipCode: zipCode ?? this.zipCode,
      cellPhone: cellPhone ?? this.cellPhone,
      officePhone: officePhone ?? this.officePhone,
      email: email ?? this.email,
      companyId: companyId ?? this.companyId,
      companyName: companyName ?? this.companyName,
      mlsId: mlsId ?? this.mlsId,
      mls: mls ?? this.mls,
      businessType: businessType ?? this.businessType,
      deviceToken: deviceToken ?? this.deviceToken,
    );
  }
}
```

In another class I try to create a new instance of the Users class like this:

```
  late final Users newUser;
```

and then I try to populate it like this:

```
newUser.businessType = selectedBusinessType;
```

The Users class also has a UsersNotifiers class that I use for state management and it works great for that as long as I am only working with the current user.

When I save the user data to the database I pass the UsersNotifierProvider to the save function and everything is fine. I want to be able to pass the new user data to the save function in the same form as the Users class and have it save to the database. Here is how I pass the current user data:

```
ref.read(usersNotifierProvider.notifier).saveUser(
                              ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider),
                              ref.read(usersNotifierProvider),
                            );
```

How do I create the new instance of the Users class so I can pass it to the save function.

Comment: add User class as a parameter in saveUser method and pass the new user instance like the other parameters.

Comment: Sounds like you want to reuse the model and view.  Just create new instances of the model, yes.